# Number Sets and Harmonics?

Tags: number-theory

I have an interesting problem, but I have no idea how to even go about solving it, or what type of mathematics it even is. It goes likes this: So suppose you have a composite number n. Factor n to get prime composition: So 110 = 2*5*11 for example. Now make a Number Set composed of every harmonic point, for each prime, and each combination of primes except n. So the first set is every 2nd point (2, 4, 6 ...), then every fifth point (5, 10, ...), then every 11th point, 22nd point, 10th point and 55th point. Now the second set is composed of numbers 2^m less than n. So (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and 64). Now Find the minimum distance of each harmonic set away from the 2^m set. So the 2nd harm. set = 0 (because 2 matches with 2). the 5th harm. set = 1 (because 5-4) = 1. And the 11th harm. set = 3 (because 11-8 = 3). 22 is 6. 10 is 2. and 55 is 9. Now take the highest number of all the sets: which in this case is 9. And 9 is the answer. So the f(110) = 9. Now do this for all numbers n. What is the upper bound function g(n) of the function previously defined f(n)? (My guess is that it is probably g(x) c*log(n) where c is some constant, that's just my random guess though).

[Update] So I figured out that the maximum numbers of f(x) are going to come from the harmonic sets of n divided by its prime factors. This is because the lower harmonics sets (2, 5, 11), are included in the upper harmonic sets.

Ex: 110/5 = 22, 110/2 = 55, 110/11 = 10;

Any knowledge to point me in the right type of maths to solve it? (Sorry if I tagged this wrong, I just thought it might involve number-theory the most because of the harmonics, and factoring in the process. That and like I said before, I have no idea what kind of mathematics this is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some computations, it appears that the highest values are those of 2^n-1 that are not prime. The upper bound for those are 2^(n+1) + 2. So the upper bound equation would be: g(x) = 2n + 2

Answer (score 0):

(Answered before it was clear you wanted an asymptotic result.)

The value of $g(n)$ can be arbitrarily large. Here is a proof. Let $N$ be a positive integer. To find a value of $n$ where $g(n)\ge N$, proceed as follows. Choose $k$ large enough so that $2^{k+1}-2^k>4N$, and let $m=\left\lceil\frac{2^k+N}{2}\right\rceil$. Note that for every integer $q$ in the interval $[2m,3m]\,$, $\lvert q-2^j\rvert>N$ for $j\le k+1$. Choose $p$ prime in that interval. [This paper](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijcms-password/ijcms-password13-16-2006/elbachraouiIJCMS13-16-2006.pdf) shows that such a $p$ exists. Then $g(p)>N$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to exclude prime numbers. (Because the bound for a prime will just be how far away it is from a 2^n number, which does increase really fast) My curiosity was for composite numbers. (Just fixed)